# How to cluster a series of right-skewed integers

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I have a series of integers. What I would like to do is split them into 5 discrete categories. I tried z-scores with bounds (-oo, -2), [-2, -1), [-1, +1], (+1, +2], (+2, +oo) but it doesn't seem to work probably because of the right-skewed data. So, I though that it might work with some sort of clustering. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On skewed data, it can help a lot to go into logspace.

You may first want to understand the distribution better, then split them.

Have you tried visualizing them, to identify appropriate splitting values?

One-dimensional data can be well visualized, and the results of a manual approach are often better than those of some blackbox clustering.